# Pass javascript string to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS variable:

```
var str = "hello world";
```

How could I pass this JS variable `str` to a PHP variable like `$str = this JS variable`?

```
echo $str; //output "hello world"
```

Comment: You can't. PHP is executed on the server, by the time the page is in the browser on the users computer and javascript is executing, it's too late to pass stuff directly to the server, you have to load another page, either the one you're on needs to be reloaded again, you redirect to another page, or you use ajax or other techniques that can load a page without the browser refreshing.

Comment: If you search here you will probably found an answer. This has been asked a gazillion times.

Comment: @adeneo: Is this posible if my PHP var is executed before the JS one?

Comment: @FelixKling - Hard to find a good duplicate at least ?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php?lq=1

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Bphp%5D++pass+js+variable+to+php

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
           var str = 'hello world';
        </script>
 <?php          
      $roo = " <script type=\"text/javascript\">
          document.write(str) ;
        </script>";

     echo $roo; // will print hello world           
  ?>
```

EDit:

or use AJAX to get javascript variables .

Comment: That's the other way round I believe.

Comment: This is the vice versa. I want the opposite one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Orion - nope, not even close.

Comment: You understand that you are just assigning a string to `$roo` containing HTML?

Comment: @Orion it should work this edited code.

Comment: `document.write(str)` is also okay

Comment: The code you posted is still incorrect, or at least doesn't solve the OP's original question.

Comment: @FelixKling incorrect ? have you tried it ?

Comment: I don't have to. I can say for certain that `$roo` doesn't have the value of the JavaScript variable (because it's impossible). All you do is generating some JS code that prints the JS variable. Maybe you are trying to be funny, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to a postback event, and in your php read it from the posted data

using an xhr request you could then also print your output